# Setting Image On ImageView Not Working - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

I am trying to set a image to a ImageView in android, by picking it from the gallery. I'm using intent to open the gallery, and OnActivityResult, to handle it. The problem is that the OnActivityResult is not working. The gallery opens, I choose the image, and then it is still the old image. There are no errors.

Here is my code for opening the gallery:

```
wallpaper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

And thats how I'm handling it:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
         String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                 filePathColumn, null, null, null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();

         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
         String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         cursor.close();

         wallpaper.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); 
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // Even the Toast is not working.

     }
}
```

I am sure, that the ImageView is declared correctly, because when I use resource as a wallpaper it is working. Any idea where is the problem coming from?

**Edit:**  onActivityResult() IS being called, but the code inside the IF is not being accessed / triggered.

This is the ImageView, which I need to change:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/wallScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/wall"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I found out that this is somehow causing the problems any idea why?

**Edit:**
ImageView declaration:

before OnCreate():

```
ImageView wallpaper;
```

inside onCreate():

```
wallpaper = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
```

and the onClickListener is already above.

I just find out that the onActivityResult() is immediately called after the gallery is open. Its not triggering the IF, because it doesn't wait me to pick a image. Any idea why is that happening?

**Solved**:

The problem was coming from that, that when the gallery was opened, my activity was restarted, and because of that OnActivityResult() was called too early. This doesn't happen on all devises but to be sure that it is going to work on all devices just add to the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Everybody, thanks for your help!

Comment: are u sure that data.getData() does not return null? Check it out

Comment: Well I think that the onActivityResult() is not being fired at all. I placed Toast just under the Uri selectedImage = data.getData(); , with string - selectedImage.toString(), but the Toast is not shown at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an running example Activity class...

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView ivSelectedPhoto;

    public static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ivSelectedPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGalery) ;
        Button btnOpenGalery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectImage);
        btnOpenGalery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent GaleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(GaleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data) {
        super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, Data);

        if (RequestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && ResultCode == RESULT_OK && null != Data) {
                Uri SelectedImage = Data.getData();
                String[] FilePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor SelectedCursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImage, FilePathColumn, null, null, null);
                SelectedCursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = SelectedCursor.getColumnIndex(FilePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = SelectedCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                SelectedCursor.close();

                ivSelectedPhoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }
}
```

I am making now for you :) You don't forget to add **@Override** on **onActivityResult()** method :)

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. I replaced mine with yours, but... In my code, and yours too, onActivityResult() IS being called, but the code inside the IF is not being accessed / triggered.

Comment: Is there any permissions needed? I have the read/write, but nothing else.

Comment: With the code in completely new project, its still the same problem, so the problem is (I hope so) not in the project. I'm running the apps on SGS3. Maybe this has something to do with it, but I don't think so.

Comment: The project that you send me is working. I found out that the problem is coming from the ImageView. Any idea why? See my edit.

Comment: All the ImageView xml code is in the question. I added it on my last edit.

Comment: You want dell **android:src="@drawable/wall"** code and insert **android:background="@drawable/wall"**.. Your code is running :) Please check the true answer this :)

Comment: Still not working :(. I'm going to post all my java declaration about the ImageView

Comment: Oh it's just a picture. JPG. I tried changing it and then try again but its still not working

Comment: please give **drawable/Wall** file and JPG image. I create yout Project and sent you..

Comment: But I need to fix the problem, with my project, because when I get it from you I still am going to place the code in my project, and the problem is still going to be there. I need to find out why the code inside the IF is not triggered.

Comment: Still not working. I just find out that the onActivityResult() is immediately called after the gallery is open. Its not triggering the IF, because it doesn't wait me to pick a image. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Please give your Project files, because nothing is very hard to find fault without.. Or compare your project with this Project; [link](http://www.anadoluprogramlama.com/TestProject.rar)

Comment: I compared it. Its EXACTLY the same. My problem is that onActivityResult() fires too early, and because of that the picture is not being set. To fix the problem, we have to find why the onActivityResult() fires so early. It fires, when the gallery opens, and it doesn't wait for me to pic an image. I can pic, but onActivityResult() is already finished.

Comment: onActivityResult is start on close galery. What is early mean ?

Comment: onActivityResult() starts, right when the gallery opens, and while I search for image, it is already checked the IF, which returns false, and thats why the image is not being set. The code inside the IF is never reached. Early means - before its supposed to. It should start when I pick an image, but it starts on the open of the gallery.

Comment: Please give your Project code, because this codes fine work to me.. I want to see your Project code because The error can be at different places..

Comment: Please click the button up next to the answers that help you :)

Comment: I am very thankful to you, but I have less than 15 reputation, and I can't upvote. Sorry.

Comment: Please chack this answer to true.. This answer has to next a tick. Please check iy :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  

        }
    }
}
```

delete **null !=data** code..

if(resultCode == RESULT_OK), data doesn't null ;)

Comment: Would you like me to send the sample project?

Comment: Well thanks, but I don't think it will help. I have done this a lots of times before, even a couple of times in the current project, but only this is not working, and I find it odd, that its not. I checked out some tutorials online, but I'm doing everything right according to them. I'm almost sure that the onActivityResult() is not even started, when I choose an image. I'll keep trying and if I succeed I will post the solution here.

Comment: I created new example class for you.. :) If you still send the project, send correct..